# Convergence of Poisson Random Variable

Tags: probability, convergence, poisson-distribution

For $n \in N $, if $X_n \sim Poisson(\frac{1}{n})$ then

PT: 
1.  $X_n  \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow \infty]{P} 0 $

2. $nX_n  \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow \infty]{P} 0 $

It says $X_n$ converges to 0 in probability.

Attempt:

$ \forall \epsilon >0, $

$Pr(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon ) = 1 - e^{-\lambda} \Sigma_{i=0}^{\lfloor{\epsilon}\rfloor} \frac{\lambda^i} {i!}  $

Putting $\lambda = \frac{1}{n}$ in the above equation, 1 is proved by saying  as limit of n approaches $\infty$, the summation is a finite sum of quantities approaching 0 therefore it is 0.

Q1. Is there a better way to prove ?

Q2. How can we prove 2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $X$ is discrete, you can simplify a little:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}p(X_n=0) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\text{e}^{-{1 \over n}} = \text{e}^{\lim_{n\to\infty}{-{1\over n}}} = \text{e}^0=1$$

where we can go from the second to the third term by the continuity of the exponentiation function.

The second statement follows from the first, as $n\cdot0 = 0$ and $n\cdot X \neq 0$ if $X \neq 0$, so $p(nX_n=0) = p(X_n=0)$, and since they are equal $\forall n$, their limits are equal too.

Comment: I was focused on $\epsilon >0 $ and totally lost the point of the question.

Comment: Well $\epsilon > 0$ is the way to go with continuous distributions, so understandable!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer for part-2:

Let $X = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n$, then we have

$$
\begin{align*}
P(X=k) & = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\,P(X_n=k) \\
& = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{n}}n^{k}k!} 
& = \begin{cases}
& 1;\qquad X_n = 0 \\
& 0;\qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

Now, using this definition of $X$, we get

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|nX_n - X| > \epsilon) & = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|nX_n|>\epsilon) \\
& = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(X_n > \frac{\epsilon}{n}) \\
& = 1 - \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(X_n \leq \frac{\epsilon}{n}) \\
& = 1 - 1 = 0\qquad\text{since, }P(X\leq 0) = 1
\end{align*}
$$

**QED!**